# Looking for command line encryption utility for Windows

Tags: windows, encryption

I am looking for command line encryption utility for Windows - paid or free. Would prefer it to support AES-256. It has to be something with large user base and actively in development. **Need to be able to specify password in command line - not looking to use private/public keys.**

It will be used as a part of my backup process. In a nutshell I would just use Winzip or 7-zip encryption but the  list of files in encrypted archive is visible and I don't like that. So the plan is to zip files without the password and then encrypt ZIP file itself.

I do use TrueCrypt but it is not convenient for this process - one has to backup whole volume which is not effective storage-wise plus one cannot create encrypted volumes from the command line as far as I know.

Basically looking for something like this: http://hcrypto.sourceforge.net/ but this software doesn't seem to be under active development.

Comment: to hide the file names you can zip the files without password then zip the zipped file with a password. the question is :  is the zip encryption secure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the command line version of 7-zip `7z.exe` you can use the `-p` switch to set a password. This will also enable header encryption ( `-mhe` option for the 7z format) which means file names will also be encrypted.

Comment: Unless the 7-zip encryption code is Open Source, I would not recommend using it.  Open Source encryption code has been vetted by more eyes, and is much harder to hide backdoors in.

Comment: 7-zip uses AES and it's LGPL v2 and I really think a guy who is competent enough to invent a widely-used archieve format knows how to use an ecryption lib correctly.

Comment: @billc.cn I agree.  I just didn't know if the source was open.  It is, so 7-zip is a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 11):

[openssl](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) is available for Windows is widely used and supports command line encryption

```
# encrypt file.txt to file.enc using 256-bit AES in CBC mode
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc
```

If necessary, you can specify the pass-phrase on the command-line

```
… -pass pass:mySillyPassword
```

or

```
… -pass file:/path/to/secret/password.txt
```

<sub>(from http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#encrypt-simple)</sub>

---

See also [this answer to a related question](https://superuser.com/a/196319/52492) that mentions GPG